# Spring - How to use BeanPropertyRowMapper without matching column names

Tags: java, spring

I work on an application that has been converted from pure JDBC to Spring template with row mapper. The issue that I have is that the column in database doesn't match the property names which prevent me from using `BeanPropertyRowMapper` easily.

I saw some posts about using aliases in queries. This would work but it makes it impossible to do a `SELECT *`

Isn't there any annotation that can be used with `BeanPropertyRowMapper` as `@Column` from JPA?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> I saw Some posts about using aliases in queries

This is actually an approach suggested in JavaDocs:

> To facilitate mapping between columns and fields that don't have matching names, try using column aliases in the SQL statement like "select fname as first_name from customer".

From: [`BeanPropertyRowMapper`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/BeanPropertyRowMapper.html).

> impossible to do a SELECT *

Please do not use `SELECT *`. This makes you vulnerable to any database schema change, including completely backward compatible ones like adding or rearranging columns.

> Isn't there any annotation that can be used with BeanPropertyRowMapper as @Column from JPA?

Yes, it is called [jpa](/questions/tagged/jpa), [hibernate](/questions/tagged/hibernate) and maybe [ibatis](/questions/tagged/ibatis). Seriously, either use aliases or implement your own `RowMapper`, Spring is not a full-featured [orm](/questions/tagged/orm).

Comment: I'm experiencing the problem described in this question now. The problem is that some databases have very restrictive limits on the length of the alias which effectively prevents the solution from working. The solution based on extending ```BeanPropertyRowMapper``` to check an annotation is more flexible.

Answer (score 6):

You can override the `BeanPropertyRowMapper.underscoreName`, and get the name of the Column annotation to mapping the field with `@Column(name = "EXAMPLE_KEY")` in the PropertyDescriptor(getter/setter binding).

```
@Slf4j
public class ColumnRowMapper<T> extends BeanPropertyRowMapper<T> {

  private ColumnRowMapper(final Class<T> mappedClass)
  {
    super(mappedClass);
  }

  @Override
  protected String underscoreName(final String name)
  {
    final Column annotation;
    final String columnName;
    Field declaredField = null;

    try
    {
      declaredField = getMappedClass().getDeclaredField(name);
    }
    catch (NoSuchFieldException | SecurityException e)
    {
      log.warn("Ups, field «{}» not found in «{}».", name, getMappedClass());
    }

    if (declaredField == null || (annotation = declaredField.getAnnotation(Column.class)) == null
        || StringUtils.isEmpty(columnName = annotation.name()))
    {
      return super.underscoreName(name);
    }

    return StringUtils.lowerCase(columnName);
  }

  /**
   * New instance.
   *
   * @param <T> the generic type
   * @param mappedClass the mapped class
   * @return the bean property row mapper
   */
  public static <T> BeanPropertyRowMapper<T> newInstance(final Class<T> mappedClass)
  {
    return new ColumnRowMapper<>(mappedClass);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

A version of [above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52534584/449553) mapper but with early initiation of mapping index, since reflection is way too slow:

```java
import java.lang.reflect.Field;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap;
import javax.persistence.Column;

import lombok.NonNull;
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.BeanPropertyRowMapper;

@Slf4j
public class ColumnRowMapper<T> extends BeanPropertyRowMapper<T> {

    private Map<String, String> columnIndex;
    
    private ColumnRowMapper(final Class<T> mappedClass)
    {
        super(mappedClass);
    }

    @Override
    protected void initialize(Class<T> mappedClass) {
        columnIndex = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
        for (Field f: mappedClass.getDeclaredFields()) {
            String fieldName = f.getName();
            Column annotation = f.getAnnotation(Column.class);
            if (annotation == null) {
                continue;
            }
            String columnName = annotation.name();
            if (StringUtils.isEmpty(columnName)) {
                continue;
            }
            columnIndex.put(fieldName, StringUtils.lowerCase(columnName));
        }
        super.initialize(mappedClass);
    }

    @Override
    protected @NonNull String underscoreName(final @NonNull String name)
    {
        if (columnIndex.containsKey(name)) {
            return columnIndex.get(name);
        }
        return super.underscoreName(name);
    }

    /**
     * New instance.
     *
     * @param <T> the generic type
     * @param mappedClass the mapped class
     * @return the bean property row mapper
     */
    public static <T> BeanPropertyRowMapper<T> newInstance(final Class<T> mappedClass)
    {
        return new ColumnRowMapper<>(mappedClass);
    }
}
```